# Empty path redirect me to an other component

Tags: angular, url, path, is-empty

I work on a angular project. I set my empty path but it's redirect directly on /swap component and I don't understand why .
I set the path like this :
Thanks for the help.
If you want more info tel me :)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'swap', component: SwapComponent}
];
```

Comment: Strange :p... It should not act like this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this....

```
const appRoutes: Routes = 
[ 
{path: 'app', component: AppComponent }, 
{path: '', redirectTo: '/app', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'swap', component: SwapComponent},
];
```